# Не работает отправка данных через $_POST с enctype

Tags: php, html

При использовании `enctype="multipart/form-data"` не работает отправка данных файла. Остальные $_POST имеются, а файлы отсутствуют

Без него все проходит и работает. В чем собственно причина?

```
HTML:
<form action="/data.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><b>Название: </b> <input type="text" name="fields[name]"></p>
<p><b>Новое изображение:</b> <input type="file" name="fields[preview]"></p>
<button name="update">Изменить</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
            print_r($_POST["fields"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: В том, что файлы надо смотреть в `$_FILES`, читайте документацию https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @andreymal я уже пробовал. Выходит ошибка - Undefined index: preview
Раньше такого вообще не было

Comment: @andreymal с fields[preview] тоже не работает. Пробовал многие варианты
Только вот непонятно, почему раньше такого не было,а сейчас проявилось

Comment: Значит выводите куда-нибудь полное содержимое массива `$_FILES` и изучайте, что же внутри него всё-таки есть

Comment: попробуй использовать нормальный name без спецсимволов.

Comment: @andreymal так получилось, но получается, что он делит мой name на массив и помещает еще каждый параметр в свой массив

Comment: @xmikex пробовал, делал просто name="preview" и не видит

Comment: Попробовал запустить код у себя и обнаружил вывернутую наизнанку структуру — `$_FILES["fields"]["name"]["preview"]` содержит имя файла, `$_FILES["fields"]["size"]["preview"]` размер, `$_FILES["fields"]["tmp_name"]["preview"]` путь к сохранённому временному файлу и так далее

Comment: @andreymal тоже самое щас вывел. Проблема в том, что раньше такого не было и он спокойно хранился в $_POST

Comment: Лично я никогда не слышал о том, чтобы файлы были в $_POST

Comment: @andreymal все прошлые проекты делал так и название хранилось в $_POST, без всяких манипуляций. Сам файл хранился-то $_FILES, но название выходило в $_POST, чего щас не наблюдается

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо)